# Any other way to add scrollbar to JPanel other than JscrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have developed a desktop application. Now in that app I want to add panel with a scrollbar. I am trying using JScrollPane, but its not working.

```
JPanel paraJPanel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane SP_para_list = new JScrollPane(paraJPanel);
add(SP_para_list).setBounds(10,30,250,350);
```

This way I am adding scrollbars to panel. But it shows only empty panel with borders. It is not showing components in the panel. Although I have added several labels in it. Is it correct? Is there any other way to add scroll bar to panel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) ***Use layouts.*** 2) When something in the toolkit does not work to your expectation, ask what you are doing wrong, rather than "How do I do Y without X?" 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the PreferredSize for the panel, to make the scrollbar show up, like below.

even you do not set a layout, the panel already has a default layout set.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel()
    {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 1000);
        }
    };
    panel.add(new JLabel("Test1"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Test2"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(panel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(600, 800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I want to set this panel to a particular position. I am not using any layout.

Comment: no, never-ever use setXXSize (it's the panel's job to return something reasonable based on its content)